# TokuDB Status & reliability

Tags: mysql, tokudb

I have been looking at ways to keep a lid on the potential size of a mySQL DB in the webapp that I plan to get into beta soon.  The DB has the potential to become very big.  Having examined what I am doing I found that using the file system to store certain data (mostly images) would have a huge impact on DB size - ensure that I would probably never have to deal with a DB that blows the TB ceiling though it might still get into 100s of GBs.  I ended up discovering TokuDB in my quest for the answer to the question - "would it be worth compressing my VARCAHAR data prior to putting it into the DB?".

The benchmarks I have seen for TokuDB are very impressive.  However, I have also run into a few comments that are less than reassuring

- It is slow on ON DUPLICATE UPDATES. This has been countered by another writer who claims that a simple switch to REPLACE INTO fixes the issue.
- It is good enough for a backup DB but not for production purposes.

Those comments are more than a year old so I was wondering... what is the current view?  I would like to hear from anyone who has experience with using TokuDB.  The tables on which I may use it have a high proportion of write accesses and typically have one largish VARCHAR column.

Comment: Hmmm... two days without an answer and no reply to my questions to Tokutek.  Does not inspire much confidence does it? Using relatively unknown closed source technology from what appears to be an unresponsive provider sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: TokuDB is now [open source](http://www.tokutek.com/2013/04/announcing-tokudb-v7-open-source-and-more/)